# gmailのHTMLをテキストへ変換したい

Tags: python, python3

Pythonでimaplibを使って、メールを読み込んでいます。
base64コード変換後、HTMLとして表示されます。
HTMLをテキストへ変換したいですが、変更するにはどのようにすれば良いでしょうか。

①print(maintext) BASE64コード状態

```
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
```

②BASE64元のデータへ戻す

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "_http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>WEB</title>
</head>
<body style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px; color: #3E403D;">
<div style="text-align: center;">
<table style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px; color: #3E403D;width: 600px; border-width: 0; margin: auto; text-align: left; direction: ltr;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="background-color: #464646; padding: 5px 20px;"><img src="https://my.iamweb.com/images/emails/logo.png" alt="web" style="vertical-align: middle;">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding:20px; line-height: 18px; border-left: solid 1px #B8B7B5; border-right: solid 1px #B8B7B5;">
<div>
<div>Hello,<br>
```

BASE64元のデータへ戻すとHTMLに変換されます。
こちらをテキストへ変換可能でしょうか。

HTMLタグを除去する関数を作成してみましたが、何も表示されないです。

```
 #HTMLタグを除去する関数を定義
 def clean_html(body_decode, strip=False):
   soup = BeautifulSoup(body_decode, 'html.parser')
   text = soup.get_text(strip=strip)
   return text

 clean_html(body_decode)
```

実現内容
不要なHTML タグを除去してテキストのみを取得したいです。

```
Hello
```

ご教授お願い致します。

全体コード

```
from smtplib import SMTP
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email import encoders
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
import imaplib, re, email, six, dateutil.parser
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
import smtplib
from email.utils import formatdate
import base64
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

mail=imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com',993)    #SMTPは993,POPは995
mail.login('example@','12345')
mail.select('test') #メールボックスの選択

#UNSEEN未読メールを読み込む
# type,data=mail.search(None,'UNSEEN') #メールボックス内にあるすべてのデータを取得ALL

#特定のメールUNSEEN未読メールを読み込む
term = u"test".encode("utf-8")
mail.literal = term
type,data=mail.search("utf-8", "UNSEEN SUBJECT")

for i in data[0].split():   #data分繰り返す
 ok,x=mail.fetch(i,'RFC822')    #メールの情報を取得
 #文字コード指定
 ms=email.message_from_string(x[0][1].decode('utf-8'))    #パースして取得

 #差出人を取得
 ad=email.header.decode_header(ms.get('From'))
 ms_code=ad[0][1]
 if(ms_code!=None):
  address=ad[0][0].decode(ms_code)
  address+=ad[1][0].decode(ms_code)
 else:
  address=ad[0][0]

 #本文を取得
 maintext=ms.get_payload()

 #出力
 print(address)
 print(maintext)
 
 #body文字コードを元に戻すbase64
 body_decode=(base64.b64decode(maintext).decode())
 print(body_decode)

 #HTMLタグを除去する関数を定義
 def clean_html(body_decode, strip=False):
   soup = BeautifulSoup(body_decode, 'html.parser')
   text = soup.get_text(strip=strip)
   return text

 clean_html(body_decode)

 mail.close()
 mail.logout()
```

Comment: HTML 自体もテキストなはずですが、不要な HTML タグを除去したい、という事でしょうか？

Comment: 回答ありがとうございました。その通りです。不要なHTML タグを除去したいです。

Comment: こんな記事の内容が応用できるのでは？ [Trying to convert html to text in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29563123/9014308), [BeautifulSoup - how should I obtain the body contents](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21452823/9014308)

Comment: @kunif さんいつも回答ありがとうごうざいます。上記の方法でもできるか。確認致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return text`の戻り値を`print`することで`clean_html`の結果が表示されるのではないでしょうか。

ご質問のコードではタイトルも取得していたので、サンプルコードでは下記の回答を参考にbodyのみを抽出する例を追加しています。
[BeautifulSoup Grab Visible Webpage Text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1983219)

**サンプルコード**

```
import base64
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.element import Comment

maintext = "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" 
#body文字コードを元に戻すbase64
body_decode=(base64.b64decode(maintext).decode())

def clean_html(body_decode, strip=False):
  soup = BeautifulSoup(body_decode, 'html.parser')
  text = soup.get_text(strip=strip)
  return text

print("# soup.get_textを使用")
print(clean_html(body_decode))

def tag_visible(element):
    if element.parent.name in ['style', 'script', 'head', 'title', 'meta', '[document]']:
        return False
    if isinstance(element, Comment):
        return False
    return True

def text_from_html(body):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(body, 'html.parser')
    texts = soup.findAll(text=True)
    visible_texts = filter(tag_visible, texts)  
    return "".join(t.strip() for t in visible_texts)

print("# soup.findAllを使用")
print(text_from_html(body_decode))
```

**実行結果**

```
# soup.get_textを使用




WEB













Hello,

# soup.findAllを使用
Hello,
```

Comment: 先ほどこちらの方法で試したら不要なHTMLを削除できました。ありがとうございました。